# paramiko: why cannot use explicitly specified key?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am using paramiko (v2.7.1) to connect to a host with an authorized key. When I do not pass the key explicitly, I can connect. However, when I pass it with `key_filename`, I get an error:

```
ValueError: ('Invalid private key', [_OpenSSLErrorWithText(code=67764350, lib=4, func=160, reason=126, reason_text=b'error:040A007E:rsa routines:RSA_check_key_ex:iqmp not inverse of q')])
```

I have checked that the path is correct, and also that the key really does match the public key on the remote host (in case we are logging in with some other method).

Also I can connect w/ `ssh` directly, both w/o explicit key and with. When I don't specify the key explicitly, ssh -vvv prints the matching path to the private key. The key is encoded using `rsa-sha2-512`. Finally, when I move the key from ~/.ssh, and clear the auth cache, I can no longer connect with ssh, proving that its definitely that key that is letting me in.

Is there something else I can do? I'm currently manually testing a script that is meant to run where the key is not installed in the default location?

My code:

```
vm = paramiko.SSHClient()
vm.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
vm.connect(
    DEST_ADDR, username=DEST_USER, key_filename=DEST_KEY_FILE, 
    )
```

The code does not work as-is, but does work if I comment out `key_filename` parameter. Are keys accessed differently depending on how they are found?

Traceback:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-57a83e5f85d1> in <module>
      3 # vm.connect(
      4 #     JUMP_ADDR, username=JUMP_USER, key_filename=JUMP_KEY_FILE)
----> 5 vm.connect(
      6     DEST_ADDR, username=DEST_USER, key_filename=DEST_KEY_FILE,
      7     ) # sock=vmchannel)

/usr/local/share/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/client.py in connect(self, hostname, port, username, password, pkey, key_filename, timeout, allow_agent, look_for_keys, compress, sock, gss_auth, gss_kex, gss_deleg_creds, gss_host, banner_timeout, auth_timeout, gss_trust_dns, passphrase, disabled_algorithms)
    433             key_filenames = key_filename
    434 
--> 435         self._auth(
    436             username,
    437             password,

/usr/local/share/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/client.py in _auth(self, username, password, pkey, key_filenames, allow_agent, look_for_keys, gss_auth, gss_kex, gss_deleg_creds, gss_host, passphrase)
    674                 for pkey_class in (RSAKey, DSSKey, ECDSAKey, Ed25519Key):
    675                     try:
--> 676                         key = self._key_from_filepath(
    677                             key_filename, pkey_class, passphrase
    678                         )

/usr/local/share/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/client.py in _key_from_filepath(self, filename, klass, password)
    584             cert_path = filename + cert_suffix
    585         # Blindly try the key path; if no private key, nothing will work.
--> 586         key = klass.from_private_key_file(key_path, password)
    587         # TODO: change this to 'Loading' instead of 'Trying' sometime; probably
    588         # when #387 is released, since this is a critical log message users are

/usr/local/share/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py in from_private_key_file(cls, filename, password)
    233         :raises: `.SSHException` -- if the key file is invalid
    234         """
--> 235         key = cls(filename=filename, password=password)
    236         return key
    237 

/usr/local/share/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py in __init__(self, msg, data, filename, password, key, file_obj)
     53             return
     54         if filename is not None:
---> 55             self._from_private_key_file(filename, password)
     56             return
     57         if (msg is None) and (data is not None):

/usr/local/share/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py in _from_private_key_file(self, filename, password)
    174     def _from_private_key_file(self, filename, password):
    175         data = self._read_private_key_file("RSA", filename, password)
--> 176         self._decode_key(data)
    177 
    178     def _from_private_key(self, file_obj, password):

/usr/local/share/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py in _decode_key(self, data)
    192             n, e, d, iqmp, q, p = self._uint32_cstruct_unpack(data, "iiiiii")
    193             public_numbers = rsa.RSAPublicNumbers(e=e, n=n)
--> 194             key = rsa.RSAPrivateNumbers(
    195                 p=p,
    196                 q=q,

/usr/local/share/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.py in private_key(self, backend)
    365     def private_key(self, backend=None) -> RSAPrivateKey:
    366         backend = _get_backend(backend)
--> 367         return backend.load_rsa_private_numbers(self)
    368 
    369     def __eq__(self, other):

/usr/local/share/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py in load_rsa_private_numbers(self, numbers)
    600         evp_pkey = self._rsa_cdata_to_evp_pkey(rsa_cdata)
    601 
--> 602         return _RSAPrivateKey(self, rsa_cdata, evp_pkey)
    603 
    604     def load_rsa_public_numbers(self, numbers):

/usr/local/share/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py in __init__(self, backend, rsa_cdata, evp_pkey)
    387         if res != 1:
    388             errors = backend._consume_errors_with_text()
--> 389             raise ValueError("Invalid private key", errors)
    390 
    391         # Blinding is on by default in many versions of OpenSSL, but let's

ValueError: ('Invalid private key', [_OpenSSLErrorWithText(code=67764350, lib=4, func=160, reason=126, reason_text=b'error:040A007E:rsa routines:RSA_check_key_ex:iqmp not inverse of q')])
```

ref: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1929

Comment: *When I do not pass the key explicitly I can connect...* sounds like you can connect without authentication, if so that's a security hole. The error message is pretty clear and has nothing to do with the connection attempt. Your private key file is corrupted, or at least that's what the error message says. It may actually be that the file is in a different format than what's expected.

Comment: no -- see ssh -vvv -- it explicitly lists key and says its signing `sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512` This is both when key is explicitly specified and also not. ... yes: I'm expecting that paramiko looks up the key differently somehow and is more picky about format (or tries wrong encoding?) if explicitly specified.... *and* when I use paramiko w/o explicit key I get `INFO:paramiko.transport:Authentication (publickey) successful!` -- not so much detail, but seemingly using a key.

Comment: The error message is clear and unmistakeable. Perhaps just for testing try with different keys.

Comment: Indeed -- and wrong! When I pass an invalid key (with debug on) it fails using that key, but then succeeds on fallback attempt. (Not sure if there is an option to turn off fallback.)

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue for paramiko 2.7.1 -- fixed by installing 2.8.0